# A variant of Morley’s trisector theorem involving external angles

Tags: geometry, triangles

This is a question about a variant of [Morley’s trisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley%27s_trisector_theorem).

> For any $\triangle ABC$, if the trisection lines of one of the angles and the trisection lines of the other two *external* angles intersect at points $X$, $Y$, $Z$, then $\triangle XYZ$ is a regular triangle.

[image]

Here is what I have tried.

1. Suppose the trisection lines of the external angles $B$ and $C$ intersect at $X$, $Q$, $R$, $S$, as shown. We can get $\angle BSX = \angle CSX$.
2. Draw $\angle SXZ = \angle SXY =30^\circ$. Intersect $BS$ and $CS$ at $Z$ and $Y$. We know $\triangle XYZ$ is a regular triangle.
3. Now I need to prove that $AY$ and $AZ$ trisect $\angle A$. First reflect point X by line BS,CS to X' and X",which X' and X"are on AB and AC.We have x'z=xz=xy=x"y.

4.Now I want to prove A,X',Z,Y,X" are on the same circle.Stucking here.
I am trying to use the same way [Dr.Naraniengar](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Morley/Naraniengar.shtml) proof this question.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you very much.:)

Comment: I wonder if [John Conway's proof (via cut-the-knot.com)](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Morley/conway.shtml) of Morley's theorem can be adapted to this variant. (RIP John Conway, 2020.)

Comment: @Blue  I believe Conway's proof indeed applies here with little modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've work out the problem!Yay! :)
[image]

Suppose the trisection lines of the external angles B and C intersect at X, Q, R, S, as shown. We can get ∠BSX=∠CSX.

Draw ∠SXZ=∠SXY=30∘. Intersect BS and CS at Z and Y. We know △XYZ is a regular triangle.

Now I need to prove that AY and AZ trisect ∠A. First reflect point X by line BS,CS to X' and X",which X' and X"are on AB and AC.We have X'Z=XZ=XY=X"Y.

Now I want to prove A,X',Z,Y,X" are on the same circle.

Draw the circumcircle of X',Z,Y,X" ,which is circle O.
We know ∠BSX=∠CSX=90-β-γ,
 so ∠BZX=30+90-β-γ=120-β-γ ,

∠X'ZY=∠X"YZ=300-2β-2γ,

∠X'ZY+∠X"YZ+OX'Z+OX"Y=900-6β-6γ,

∠X'OX"=540-(900-6β-6γ)=6β+6γ-360,

The inscribed angle of ∠X'OX" is 3β+3γ-180,which is equal to ∠A=180-(180-3β)-(180-3γ)=3β+3γ-180, hence A is on circle O.

since X'Z=ZY=X"Y,finally got ∠X'AZ=∠ZAY=∠YAX".